# dataset relation in c# for two columns

Tags: c#, sql, dataset

I would really appreciate a help in this code. I have a `DataSet` with two tables; I need to create a relation based on two columns as primary key:

```
public DataSet GetAll()
{
    string sql = $@"SELECT * FROM Journal ORDER BY JvNO, cYear;
                    SELECT * FROM JournalDetail ORDER BY JvNO, cYear";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(GlobalConfig.ConnString()))
    {
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);

        ds.Relations.Add("Journal_Batch", new DataColumn[] { ds.Tables[0].Columns["JvNO"], ds.Tables[0].Columns["cYear"] }, 
                                          new DataColumn[] { ds.Tables[1].Columns["JvNO"], ds.Tables[1].Columns["cYear"] });

        return ds;
    }
}
```

Currently, I'm doing it like this and it's working but I need it with `DataSet` relation:

```
public DataSet GetJournalByID(int JVNO, int cYear)
{
    string sql = $@"SELECT * FROM Journal WHERE JvNO = { JVNO } and cYear = { cYear };
                    SELECT * FROM JournalDetail WHERE JvNO = { JVNO } and cYear = { cYear };";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(GlobalConfig.ConnString()))
    {
            connection.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            da.Fill(ds);

            return ds;
    }
}
```

I don't know what's wrong with first code, as it returns all matching `JvNO` **or** `Year`.

i want to use the first one to fill two grids as follow:

```
    private void GetData()
    {
        DataSet currentDs = new DataSet();

        grdJournalDetails.DataSource = null;
        grdJournal.DataSource = null;

        JournalConnector journalConnection = new JournalConnector();
        currentDs = journalConnection.GetAll();

        grdJournal.DataSource = currentDs.Tables[0];
        grdJournalDetails.DataSource = currentDs.Tables[1];
    }
```

then with each row selected from **grdJournal** to display **grdJournalDetails** with related data without calling each time the second snippet of code.

i used Dapper and i'm familiar with it, but with devexpress grid, it have to be a datatable to use the event **gvJournal_FocusedRowChanged**, otherwise datarow returns always null;

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: It is not clear how do you use the first code. While in the second code snippet you set a where condition that limits your result, the first one has no where conditions, so every row from the first table and every row from the second table are returned. If you want to get the rows from the JournalDetail that are in relation with a certain row in the Journal table you need to use the Journal DataRow.GetChildRows method.

Comment: You may want to look into SQL's 'JOIN' keyword if you want to retrieve related data from several tables. You are now just retrieving unrelated records from two tables using two separate SQL commands.

Comment: Thank you guys, yes i want to return all rows not only one into two grids, hence for each row in table **journal** returns all rows from **journaldetail** as if no relation was made at all

Comment: thank you @Steve i guess i start to figure out yes you are right, just i thought i have an issue with relation in the DataSet as if i'm doing it wrongly.